# my view looks different on iphone 5 and iphone 6 even though it has constraints - what is wrong here?

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard, nslayoutconstraint, cagradientlayer

In my `swift` app I am applying gradient to my view. I do it with the following code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var gradientView: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let layer = CAGradientLayer()
    layer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.gradientView.frame.width, height: self.gradientView.frame.height)
    layer.colors = [UIColor.clear.cgColor, UIColor.white.cgColor]
    gradientView.layer.addSublayer(layer)
}
```

in my storyboard the `gradientView` is the black one here:

[image]

its constraints are:

[image]

so it touches edges on each side, the top and the white panel on the bottom.

When I run it in iphone5 simulator I have:

[image]

and that's fine. But when I run it on iphone 6s, I see:

[image]

What's the problem here, since the constraints are applied?

Comment: replace frames with bounds http://www.andrewgertig.com/2013/08/ios-bounds-vs-frame

Comment: gradientView.bounds.width

Comment: When ViewDidLoad is called everything is the size that it is in the NIB file, which is almost always wrong.  You should to get in the habit of putting all size dependent code in viewDidLayoutSubviews for UIViewControllers and in layoutSubviews for UIViews, otherwise you will also have this problem if the user changes the screen size by rotation or by using split screen on  iPad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `gradientView`'s frame is not updated yet in `viewDidLoad`. Try this instead:

```
let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer() 

override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()   
    gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.clear.cgColor, UIColor.white.cgColor]
    gradientView.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews(){
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    gradientLayer.frame = gradientView.bounds
}
```